# how to get directory absolute of file without use ../

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
<script src="../../../../public/js/base/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../public/css/style.css">
```

This way is too long. How to get real directory without ../

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: I guess you could use absolute paths... How is your folder structure?

Comment: This is way too little information for us to help you. I'd say put the files in the same directory as your HTML file

Comment: i've just updated image

Comment: What is the root of your project? How do you access the web page?

Comment: the root is appBuild

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the absolute path (`file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/appBuild/public/js/base/angular.min.js` in this case) or set the HTML base in the header like this:

```
<head>
    <base href="file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/appBuild/public">
</head>
```

and then use paths like this:

```
<script src="js/base/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

---

However, the best solution is probably to avoid such deep folder structures altogether.